# how to sum a variable by ID and date (back for all values during two years)

Tags: r, date, sum

my data (ID, date (Y-m-d), points), I want to sum points for each ID during two years past plus to the current date (current date is the specific date as the starting date is (2012-01-01)). then starting date is (2013-01-01).

[image: data]

[image: expected output]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your data in a reproducible way. You can use `dput`

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>% filter(date > 2010-01-01 & date < 2012-12-31) %>%
group_by(ID) %>% summarise(sum_2012 == sum(points))
```

The interval of dates you can change in the **filter** statement. In my example it will be all the points between 1-jan-2010 and 31-dec-2012.